# Promises in put request

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a route for `put`, and I use it like: 
`axios.put('-SomeIp-/-SomeRoute-', SomeData);`

Do I have to put `.then` after it or not?

In which cases do I use .then?

Comment: No, you don't have to. You won't have a way to access the response then, though.

Comment: Things are never necessary unless you have requirements.

Comment: What are you wanting to do with it?  As far as I know you never have to add a `.then()` callback to a promise if you don't need it.

Comment: I just want to save the data that was sent to the server with put

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no requirement to register a callback for a promise.

If you don't want to run a function when it resolves, then don't tell it to run a function with `then`.